# Spring transaction and PersistenceContext

Tags: proxy, transactions, entitymanager

I've got situation like this:

```
@Transactional
@Override
public void register(String username, UserPasswordNew userPasswordNew, UserAccount userAccount) throws UserNameAlreadyExistsException {
    .....
    entityManager.merge(userAccountToSave);
}
```

I made some research but check me if I understand well. I've got `entityManager` (transaction scope). Method register is `@Transactional` so it means that this method is wrapped in proxy. When persistence context is created ? During the first call of `entityManager.merge ()` ?? Transaction is commit after method because it's wrapped in proxy. So persistence context is removed after commit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I am wrong, but you are using transaction scoped entitymanager, so during each call to entitymanager it ensure that persistence context exists, here entitymanager creates a new one and uses it to merge - and,as in transaction-scoped entitymanager, persistence context will be removed after each commit.